# Export to pdf overflowing to different page

Tags: reporting-services, printing, properties, ssrs-2008-r2, landscape

I am formatting reports and while previewing the page is overflowing 
I would like to have Tablix and 2 charts on a single page.

Please see below:
[image: DesignTablixCharts]

I made sure there are no Page breaks in either Tablix or the charts...

I checked `Report -> Report Properties -> Landscape` and also made sure 
margins are 0.5in and width > height.

Please let me know what am I missing here?

Thanks
Aruna

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of the body of the report, does this go over the landscape size? If it does it will go over onto 2 pages when you preview the report.